# How make dynamic function name in foreach loop? PHP

Tags: php

I just discovered how to make dynamic name for variables in a foreach, but I can't find how to make dynamic names for functions.

I have this foreach loop:

```
       $array=array(
                   array("func1"  ,"15"), 
                  array("func2"  ,"30")
            );

            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
              $counter++;
              if($value[1] <= ($start_date2 - ${'save_time'.$key})){    
                  ${'save_time'.$key} = $start_date2;
                  echo "modul ".$value[0]." #".$counter."  !\r\n";
                  echo "function: ".$value[0]."\r\n";

                  ${$value[0]."()"}; // ?? LIKE THIS 
                  {$value[0]."()"}; // ?? When i try this i have error
                  // here i need every loop dynamic name of my funcnion like
                  func1();

              }   
            }

        function func1(){
        // some code..
        }

        function func2(){
        // some code..
        }
```

Comment: Just `$value[0]();`

Answer (score 0):

you try function [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) — Call a callback with an array of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are at least two ways to do that, one specified by @billyonecan in his comment, which is closer to what you apparently are trying to do, and the other is the one linked by @QuanLee.

Both ways are counter-intuitive and are something not recommended to be **done** due to the lack of standards around it. If you write your code like that, you are adding gunpowder to a time bomb which will be the maintenance of the code you are writing.

But, nevertheless, using the **first approach** you can do it like this:

```
// Without parameters
function test()
{
    return 'cool';
}

$string = 'test';
echo $string() . "\n";

// With parameters
function testParameter($okay)
{
    return "$okay, really?";
}

$string = 'testParameter';
echo $string( 'again' ) . "\n";
```

And using the **second approach**, like this:

```
// Without parameters
function test()
{
    return 'cool';
}

$string = 'test';
echo call_user_func_array($string, array()) . "\n";

// With parameters
function testParameter($okay)
{
    return "$okay, really?";
}

$string = 'testParameter';
echo call_user_func_array($string, array('Damn'));
```

Now, if you MUST do that in your code, I would recommend using the `call_user_func_array`, because like this you can, at least, track the usage of it in your code, what would be much harder to do using variable names.